# Am I doing this right? - Paypal IPN Work

Tags: php, paypal

So, my current notify_url is not being hit at all after the purchase button is clicked. It's not my webserver, it's not a firewall, it has to do with something regarding the encoding of the url. Any ideas, ladies, gentlemen?

P.S; I do receive the payment though, but my notify_url is not being hit, paypal IPN is enabled, and because of the notify_url not being hit, my clientele can not receive their online inventory. :\

```
    $paypalurl = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&amount=".urlencode($row['price']).
"&business=".urlencode($paypalemail)."&item_name=".urlencode($row['name'])."
&item_number=".urlencode($row['ID']."_".$_SESSION['ID'])."
&return=".urlencode("http://example.net/Test0/buynow.php")."
&rm=2&notify_url=".urlencode("http://example.net/Test0/gateway/paypalipn.php")."
&cancel_return=".urlencode("http://example.net/Test0/buynow.php")."
&no_note=1&currency_code=USD";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if the IPN notify_URL is properly working? Have you tried the notify_URL in the IPN simulator or probably in [this link](https://www.hurl.it/) to see the IPN listener is returning 200 http status?

Comment: It was surprisingly the firewall causing the issue, the IPN notify_URL is working correctly, and the IPN Listener was returning HTTP 200 Status. Thank-you, so much.